# I+be+telling you to

Tags: grammar

1. I was telling him to come down.
2. I was asking him to come down.
3. I was telling him, "Come down, come down."

Are all these three sentences correct?

Comment: #2 needs a "to" after "him." Others are correct ignoring punctuation.

Comment: (1) is correct. You have left a word out of (2).  (3) at least needs the  quoted speech to start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

1. I was telling him to come down.
   Correct.
2. I was asking him to come down.
   Correct.
3. I was telling him "come down, come down"
   Needs capitalization and punctuation.

   > I was telling him, "Come down, come down."

Comment: OK thanks, but I couldn't find any sentences with "telling to" on the internet.

Comment: Tell is usually used with the person you are speaking to coming directly after the word tell, with what you are telling after that.  Tell him to come down, tell Jake about the test, tell mom I love her, I'm telling you to stop bothering me, etc